# Virtual Raster and alpha band in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to use Virtual Raster but I meet an issue with the alpha white band of one of my 2 rasters merged. In fact the white mask appears over the layer that is under and hide some details.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing each of the 3 main bands to int16 and then setting the value as -1 where the alpha band is 0, then removing the alpha band before mosaicking did the trick (where nodata = -1)

If you're desperate this may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5YTnV0hEHc

Alternatively, Arc allows you to construct a "Mosaic Dataset", which is a bit more seamless